# Валидация не работает

Tags: yii2, валидация

Есть такой код:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['text', 'isLogged'],
        [['text'], 'required', 'message' => 'Заполните это поле'],
        ['text', 'string','min' => 6, 'tooShort' => 'Слишком короткое сообщение'],
    ];

}
public function isLogged($attribute)
{
    if (!$this->hasErrors())
    {
    if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest)
            $this->addError($attribute, 'Необходимо авторизироваться');
    }

}
```

Работает все, кроме функции `isLogged`. Что я уже только не попробовал, разные вариации добавления этой функции. Она даже не срабатывает, пробовал добавлять `exit()` в самое начало функции.

Вот здесь можете в этом убедиться http://alexsportfolio.esy.es/web/post/index. (А в исходном коде можно найти строку `Необходимо авторизоваться` в самом конце кода. Это в другом варианте добавления функции)

Так я тоже пробовал:

```
public function rules(){
    return [
        [['text'], 'required', 'message' => 'Заполните это поле'],
        ['text', 'string', 'min' => 6, 'message' => 'Слишком короткое сообщение'],
        ['text', 'required', 'when' => function($model){
              return (Yii::$app->user->isGuest);
            },'message'=>'Необходимо авторизироваться'],
    ];
}
```

Comment: Возможно нужно описать `scenario` при котором будет происходить данная валидация. Что-то типа `public function scenarios() { $scenarios = ['some_scenario' => ['text'], ];    return array_merge(parent::scenarios(), $scenarios);`

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Пример inline-валидации [из документации](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#inline-validators) Yii2 framework:

```
use yii\base\Model;

class MyForm extends Model
{
    public $country;
    public $token;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // an inline validator defined as the model method validateCountry()
            ['country', 'validateCountry'],

            // an inline validator defined as an anonymous function
            ['token', function ($attribute, $params) {
                    if (!ctype_alnum($this->$attribute)) {
                        $this->addError($attribute, 'The token must contain letters or digits.');
                    }
                }],
        ];
    }

    public function validateCountry($attribute, $params)
    {
        if (!in_array($this->$attribute, ['USA', 'Web'])) {
            $this->addError($attribute, 'The country must be either "USA" or "Web".');
        }
    }
}
```

Ваш код корректен.

Вам необходимо проверить:

- Наличие поля `text` в текущем сценарии, если объявлены `scenarios`
- Отсутствие переопределения массива `rules` возможным наследником модели или кодом.

Если валидация всё-равно работать не будет то берите этот пример и добавляйте к нему ваш функционал, до тех пор пока не столкнетесь с тем что валидация перестанет работать. Так вы поймете в каком месте ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо вызвать функцию validate() на сервере. Например в контроллере)

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score 0):

Если в форме вместо стандартного поля из коллекции Yii используется нестандартное поле/виджет (например виджет kartik`а), то дополнительные свои rules могут уже не сработать.